# How to send a message to user using Microsoft teams REST API?

Tags: c#, microsoft-teams

I am working on consuming Microsoft teams REST API. Where I am able to send a message using the channel in the group. My concern is how to send a message to an individual person?

Answer (score 2):

@Sagar Patil Currently there are no API's to send a message to the user in 1:1 chat.

Comment: is it possible to have calls between the user in 1:1?